# rename move files incrementally with php

Tags: php, rename, move

I want to rename/move a file which I can do OK with the following code but how can I take the next file in the A1 directory and move it to the A2 directory without specifying the file name?

(the files in the A1 directory are numbered from 1.txt to 1000.txt

```
<?php
rename("/home/vol11_1/htdocs/A1/1.txt", "/home/vol11_1/A2/txt.txt");
?>
```

Each time the php script is run it should move the next file from the A1 folder to the A2 folder and overwrite the txt.txt file which is already there.

How can this be done?

Thanks

Comment: save the last moved file anywhere, f.e. in session

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: new version, try this:

```
<?php

// start new or resume existing session
session_start();

// get the last file number stored on session or 0 at the first time
$last = isset($_SESSION['last']) ? $_SESSION['last'] : 0;

// increment the number
$last++;

// store on session
$_SESSION['last'] = $last;

// move the file
rename("/home/vol11_1/htdocs/A1/$i.txt", "/home/vol11_1/A2/txt.txt");

?>
```

Comment: Thanks but that script doesn't do anything, no files moved. ?

Comment: put examples of source and destinations file paths

Comment: I changed the script from 
    rename("/home/vol11_1/htdocs/A1/$i.txt", "/home/vol11_1/A$i/txt.txt");              
to    
    rename("/home/vol11_1/htdocs/A1/$i.txt", "/home/vol11_1/A2/txt.txt");

it moves a file ok but the next time I run the script it doesnt move anything because I thought it wouldnt overwrite it but even if I delete the file from A2 and run the script again it doesnt move any file?

Comment: do the files have to be named 1 to 1000? if so after the first file is moved 1.txt the next one to be moved is 2.txt

Comment: in fact all files are being deleted from A1 and a single file is being moved to A2

Comment: rename will move the file, you need this or a copy ?

Comment: I managed to do it with the following code
       $from = '/A1';
       $files = scandir($from);

      $to = '//A2';
      if (!empty($files[2])) {
      rename("{$from}/{$files[2]}", "{$to}/text.txt");
      }
Thanks to all who helped.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it with the following code

```
$from = '/A1';
$files = scandir($from);

$to = '//A2';
if (!empty($files[2])) {
rename("{$from}/{$files[2]}", "{$to}/text.txt");
}
```

Thanks to all who helped.